# Metro station stop design to prevent people from commiting suicide

Tags: user-behavior, physical, psychology, safety

How to design a metro train stop that would prevent people from endangering themselves by accessing the rails when a metro arrives (perhaps by implementing the design of special doors or elevators leading into the train itself)?

Answer (score 26):

Turin's unmanned tube (Italy) has barriers that extend from the quay to the ceiling of the basement. It is virtually impossible to fall on the tracks without tampering with the automatic doors.

Pratical example:

[image: Turin's Tube]

(Operating: **https://youtu.be/Fab0mLzBxts?t=70**)

I think this is a great solution.

Comment: I've seen this applied in many other countries as well

Comment: This is essentially a horizontal elevator shaft design.

Comment: Just to add a (needless?) example, line C of metro in Rome has the same setup.

Answer (score 8):

In Japan they use fences to stop this from happening.
[image]

Comment: This surely acts like a barrier for children but I think full walls like Gabriele suggested are far more effective for suicide attempts.

Comment: I have seen this in London, Paris and not completely sure but I think Madrid's Airport has it as well

Answer (score 4):

You can't design a sign that stops people from doing that, you would need something physical which makes it impossible to enter the rails, just like in cities like singapur, where a gate is placed in front of the rails which only opens when the train opened it doors so people can enter.

What you can do is place something like a printed line 1 meter before the rails on the ground with flashy colors like yellow/red/pink etc. and place a text like "Watch your step" etc. between it.

Bonus points if you don't just use a printed line but use a physical line that has a different texture/height then the ground, people will automatically be aware that they are close to the rails when stepping on that.

Found an example on google which shows you what i mean

[image]

Comment: "Bonus points if you don't just use a printed line but use a physical line" - Isn't it actually required by law? For blind people and the like?

Comment: Yes and no. Those kinds of lines are problematic for people with mobility issues, e.g., wheelchair users, older people, people with bad knees

Comment: "_different texture/height_" A different _texture_ – such as dimples that are sometimes seen/felt – yes. Something with a different _height_ is likely to cause _more_ harm from people tripping over it than it would save!

Answer (score 0):

london Westminster tube stop has physical barriers that make it impossible to cross onto the railway. Double doors synchronise with the train doors on arrival, like the double doors on a lift.

Comment: It's actually the Jubilee Line which was built to this spec ( being a more modern line )